# passing object pointer as protocol pointer

Tags: objective-c

```
@protocol protoA <NSObject>
@end

@interface objA : NSObject<protoA> {
    @private
    }
@end

@implementation objA
@end

@protocol protoB <NSObject>
    -(void) foo: (id <protoA> *) par;
@end

@interface objB : NSObject<protoB> 
    -(void) foo: (id <protoA> *) par;
@end

@implementation objB
    -(void) foo: (id <protoA> *) par
    {
    //...
    }
@end
```

in some other class method i use it this way:

```
objB *obj1 = [[objB alloc] init];
objA *obj2 = [[objA alloc] init];

[obj1 foo: obj2];
```

I have compiler error: "Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to '__autoreleasing id*' is disallowed with ARC

What is the proper way to do get this functionality ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`id` already is a pointer-type, use just `id<Protocol>` instead of `id<Protocol>*`.

Answer (score 4):

`id` is a pointer already, drop `*`:

```
-(void) foo: (id <protoA>) par
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify type and protocol, you can use this form:

```
- (void)method:(MONType<MONProtocol>*)param;
```

If you want an opaque objc type (`id`) and protocol, use this form:

```
- (void)method:(id<MONProtocol>)param;
```