# ARC, Protocols, Pointers and an Error

Tags: objective-c, pointers, protocols

I am getting **`Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to '__autoreleasing id<MY_AccountDAO>' is disallowed with ARC`**.

I reviewed this question: [Passing object pointer as protocol pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174748/passing-object-pointer-as-protocol-pointer) but it is a different issue and I am already using the suggested syntax in the answer.

I am getting the error in the line:

```
[accountService setAccountDAO:accountDAO];
```

Specifically the `accountDAO` reference has the little orange triangle beneath it.

**@implementation MY_Bootstrapper**

```
#import "MY_Bootstrapper.h"
#import "MY_MainController.h"
#import "MY_ServiceManager.h"

#import "MY_FileSystemAccountDAO.h"
#import "MY_AccountDAO.h"

#import "MY_AccountService.h"
#import "MY_BasicAccountService.h"

@implementation MY_Bootstrapper 

-(MY_MainController *)initializeMainController{
    MY_MainController *mainController = [MY_MainController alloc];
    mainController = [mainController init];

    MY_ServiceManager *serviceManager = [MY_ServiceManager alloc];
    serviceManager = [serviceManager init];

    MY_BasicAccountService *accountService = [MY_BasicAccountService alloc];
    accountService = [accountService init];

    id<MY_AccountDAO> accountDAO = [[MY_FileSystemAccountDAO alloc] init];

    [accountService setAccountDAO:accountDAO];

    serviceManager.accountService = accountService;

    return mainController;
}

@end
```

**@interface  MY_FileSystemAccountDAO**

```
@interface MY_FileSystemAccountDAO : MY_FileSystemDAO <MY_AccountDAO>

@end
```

**@interface MY_BasicAccountService**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MY_BasicService.h"
#import "MY_AccountService.h"

@interface MY_BasicAccountService : MY_BasicService <MY_AccountService>

- (void) setAccountDAO:(id<MY_AccountDAO> *)accountDAO;

@end
```

Comment: show `@interface` of `MY_FileSystemAccountDAO`

Comment: did you import the header?

Comment: What Bryan said. Did you import the .h that defines the protocol in your `MY_Bootstrapper.m`?

Comment: @BryanChen - Imports added.

Comment: Show the .h for your `MY_BasicAccountService` class (or it's base) so we can see the `setAccountDAO:` method (or its property).

Comment: what type does `setAccountDAO:` take?

Comment: Like rmaddy and Bryan Chen said, I bet you are making exactly the mistake from the question you link in your MY_BasicAccountService header.

Comment: @Chuck - I lack the asterisk that was the source of the original problem in that question.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi: No, it is there: `- (void) setAccountDAO:(id<MY_AccountDAO> *)accountDAO;` — See the asterisk?

Comment: @Chuck - That is not the offending line.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi: Yes, it is. The offending line is a call to that method.

Comment: @Chuck - No it is this line:     [accountService setAccountDAO:accountDAO];

Comment: @Chuck - I see now. It was the declaration in the BasicAccountService class not the use in the Bootstrapper class.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi Chuck is correct. Having the asterisk in your declaration of the `setAccontDAO:` method is causing the error on the line where you call it. Get rid of the asterisk.

Comment: Well, specifically it was that the usage didn't match the declaration — just like in the question I put as a duplicate, you were passing an object type to a parameter of a pointer type.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yep I fixed it. I didn't realize that the correction was in the recently posted class not in the Bootstrapper class itself. Objective C syntax is sufficiently new to me that I didn't immediately see that you were referring to the original method declaration not the usage in the current class (where the error was occurring).

Comment: In any event - Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void) setAccountDAO:(id<MY_AccountDAO> *)accountDAO;
```

That line declares that `accountDAO` is a pointer to a pointer, since `id` is implicitly a pointer.  The correct declaration is simply

```
- (void) setAccountDAO:(id<MY_AccountDAO>) accountDAO;
```

Comment: Still get the error and I lose some type clarity. Full disclosure: I am porting something that was originally in Java into Objective C.

Comment: this is wrong. you can do `SomeClass<SomeProtocol> *var = [SubClassConformProtocol new];`